# $\int_0^{\pi/2}sin^p\,\theta\;cos^q\,\theta\;d\theta = \frac{\Gamma{\frac{p+1}{2}}\Gamma{\frac{q+1}{2}}}{2\Gamma{\frac{p+q+2}{2}}},\; p,q > -1$

Tags: calculus

Show that: $$\int_0^{\pi/2}sin^p\,\theta\;cos^q\,\theta\;d\theta = \frac{\Gamma{\frac{p+1}{2}}\Gamma{\frac{q+1}{2}}}{2\Gamma{\frac{p+q+2}{2}}},\; p,q > -1$$

Here's the question.

[image]

Comment: Did you mess up $\sqrt{.}$ with $\Gamma(.)$?

Comment: Please, have a look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Properties

Comment: I have never seen Gamma function written like that in print!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that the OP meant the Gamma function instead of square root. If so the relation is true, as from the Beta function we have:

$$\int_0^1 v^{y-1}(1-v)^{x-1} dv = \frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}$$

Then substituting $v = \sin^2 \theta$ will provide you with the result.

Answer (score 5):

The announced result is *not right*, as may be seen by taking $q=1$ giving
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^p\,\theta\;\cos^q\,\theta\;d\theta =\int_0^1u^p\,du=\frac1{p+1}\ne \frac{\sqrt{p+1}}{2\sqrt{p+3}},\quad p>-1,
$$ in general.

Answer (score 3):

if $p=q=1$,  we get

$$\int_0^\frac {\pi}{2} \frac {\sin (2\theta)d\theta}{2} $$

$$=\frac {1}{4}[-\cos (2\theta)]_0^\frac {\pi}{2} $$

$$=\frac {1}{2} \neq \frac {1}{2\sqrt {2}} $$

Your formula doesn't seem to be correct.